# How does a 32/64 bit system store numbers?

Tags: 64-bit, storage

Was wondering how numbers get stored. Either they save for instance the number 1 in binary as 000(31/63 zeroes)1 or just a 1? And how do they know when its a new number? With other words how does it differentiate between 2 x 1 and a 3? And wouldnt a 64 bit system would cost more storage if they would store like this 000(63 zeroes)1?

Comment: [Wiki binary number counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Counting_in_binary). It would depend on further circumstances like data type etc. how the actual in memory representation looks.

Comment: I think using a web search should suffice for this type of question. You seem confused about storage and ram, what's actually taking place. Not everything takes a 64 bit chunk or 32 bit. There are bits, bytes, nibbles, words... Architecture (x86 x64) does it's job according to the software. Storage is different. Check out this site: http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/32-bit-and-64-bit-explained.htm

Comment: "Was wondering how numbers get stored." - In a memory register.

Answer (score 2):

Data is stored in units of *bytes* – the number 1 would, at minimum, take up 8 bits: `00000001`, and always starts and ends at a byte boundary. When the CPU accesses data in RAM, it addresses the whole byte, not individual bits.

The "64-bit" label merely means that all memory *addresses* are 4 bytes long (and naturally that the CPU has instructions for working with numbers that large).

But it does not change how programs store all *other* kinds of data. For everything else, the program (i.e. its author) can choose the preferred size, as long as it's an exact number of bytes. For example, in C, a variable declared as `short` or `uint16_t` will be 16 bits, i.e. 2 bytes. The usual sizes are 8, 16, 32, 64 bits (that is, 1, 2, 4, or 8 bytes), since that's what CPUs were made to work with.

(Of course, programs can store data in whatever way they want – many on-disk file formats *do* pack numbers into 3 bytes or 5 bytes or whatever – but it's more complicated to work with.)

---

To continue with your question, how does "the system" distinguish between a single 32-bit number and e.g. two 16-bit ones – the answer is that it *doesn't need to*. It's all decided when the program is written and/or compiled, so the resulting CPU instructions just directly work with the specific sizes.

(It is actually common for a program to interpret the same data different ways – e.g. even though text might be stored as a series of 1-byte chars, functions like strpos() use speed-up tricks which rely on interpreting the exact same data as series of 4-byte or even 8-byte numbers.)

Comment: There are some more interesting details: For example the alignment of the data. For some architectures, a byte can be stored at any address, but a 16 bit number can only be stored on even addresses and a 32 bit number only on addresses which can be divided by 4...